# debugging a laravel 10 cron job

Tags: laravel

I have created a cron job in laravel 10. Runs fine in Dev but fails in prod.
Looking for help on how to debug it

this is my kernel.php

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
     protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
     {
        $schedule->command('email:cron')
        ->everyFifteenMinutes();
     }

     protected function commands(): void
     {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
     }
 }
```

This is the cronfile, i have removed some for brevity.
In prod I never see the log output in the handle() function

```
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'email:cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info("(".__LINE__.") ".__FILE__." -->".__METHOD__." Starting email Cron\n");

    }
}
```

In the dev env, I get:

```
  php artisan schedule:run

  2024-03-06 20:49:06 Running ['artisan' email:cron] ........................1,008ms DONE
  ⇂ '/usr/bin/php8.2' 'artisan' email:cron > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

In prod I get:

```
 php artisan schedule:run

  2024-03-06 20:52:58 Running ['artisan' email:cron]..................... 190ms FAIL
  ⇂ '/usr/bin/php8.2' 'artisan' email:cron > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

Comment: 1. Did you set your cron correctly? 2. Did you set cron on the correct user?

Comment: If you're getting a `FAIL` flag, you should check the Laravel logs, it should tell you what's going on.

Comment: Remove /usr/bin/php8.2. Instead write "php"

Comment: - Yes, the cron is the correct user.
- there is nothing in the laravel.log file